# Unique numbers with $P^aQ^bR^c \mod N$ for each combination of $a,b,c$ possible? Would it be safer than separate form (like $T^a \mod P$ for each)?

Tags: cryptanalysis, algorithm-design, attack, known-plaintext-attack

---

### Main question: Is the computation of $a,b,c$ in $P^aQ^bR^c \mod N$ (much) harder than in $T_p^a \mod P$, $T_q^b \mod Q$, $T_r^c \mod R$ ?

(assuming the first form exists)

---

### $P^aQ^bR^c \mod N$

With $P^aQ^bR^c$ you create unique numbers (e.g. with primes $P,Q,R$) for combinations of $a,b,c$ with $a=0..a_{max},b=0..b_{max},c=0..c_{max}$, in total $(a_{max}+1)(b_{max}+1)(c_{max}+1)=M$ different numbers. The highest number you can generate will be much higher than $M$. (For usage purpose each max exponent value should be about the same size (<+/-25%)).

Now is there a way to remove the gaps and make it cyclic by computing

$P^aQ^bR^c \mod N$

instead, which still generates $M$ different numbers, but the highest number is much closer to $M$, best case $N<M+4$. For security reasons $P,Q,R$ and $M$ should be high numbers (impact?). Furthermore it need to by cyclic. So for values greater than max exponent values it starts again.

Or more general $a,b,c$ are part of a set of numbers each, instead of an continuous interval, e.g. $a \in A$ and $M=|A||B||C|$. Successor and predecessor of each member need to be quite easy to compute. Or higher $N$ with $N < kM$, and $k<<M$.

---

### Use case and possible attack

Target use case would be an algorithm which computes some sort of ciphers $e$ which have the form $e_{abc}= P^aQ^bR^c \mod N$. But instead of direct computation it starts at a given $e_0$ (user dependend) and computes a next with e.g.

$e_{a+1}'=e_0P \mod N$ , or

$e_{b+1}'=e_0Q \mod N$ , or

$e_{c+1}'=e_0R \mod N$

or also combinations or multiple steps is possible, like

$e'=eP^2Q^{42}R \mod N$.

After this $e'$ will be the next $e_0$ and you can do the same again (any you like).
Different to most other crypto algorithms the cipher $e$ is not to main interest. The way how to compute it (out of another) should be secured.
A potential attacker does know the source code and all runtime variables. So he knows his current $e_0$ as well (and $P,Q,R,N$). He does not know his current $a_0,b_0,c_0$. It should be as hard as possible to compute those. Furthermore he can get the knowledge  of other $e_j$. As above it should be hard to compute $a_{j},b_{j},c_{j}$ with $e_j = P^{a_j}Q^{b_j}R^{c_j} \mod N$ and also the computation $e_j$ out of $e_0$, which need $a_{0j},b_{0j},c_{0j}$ in $e_j = e_0P^{a_{0j}}Q^{b_{0j}}R^{c_{0j}} \mod N$ should be hard in most cases.

How would an attacker derive $a,b,c$? 3 times discrete logarithm? factorization needed?

---

### Separate form, like $T^a \mod P$

Alternative way would be

$u = T_p^a \mod P$

$v = T_q^b \mod Q$

$w = T_r^c \mod R$

With $P,Q,R$ primes and $T_i$ a corresponding prime root. (any better?)

Out of $u,v,w$ a single variable from $0$ to $M-1$ could be computed. But in use case those $u,v,w$  are internal variables of source code and a potential attacker can see those anyways. So in this case a cipher $e_0$ has 3 parts $(u_0,v_0,w_0)$. A next cipher $e_0'$ could be

$e_0'=(u_0T_p \mod P, v_0, w_0 T_r \mod R)$

In this case an attack need to compute 3 times discrete algorithm to get $a,b,c$, right?.

---

Assuming the form $P^aQ^bR^c \mod N$ exists. Would there be any benefit using it to increase the security of $a,b,c$?

### Edit:

Did some testing. With $N=173, P=3, Q=5, R=7, a,b,c \in[0..3]$ this form generates 64 unique numbers. But it is not cyclic.

So far I only found a 2D which is cyclic as well: $N=126, P=17, Q=13, (R=1), a,b \in[0..5]$ generates 36 unique numbers.

Comment: Regarding "also the computation [of] $e_j$ out of $e_0$ [...] should be hard in most cases", surely that's trivial if the attacker knows all the parameters. After all, the legitimate user should presumably be able to compute $e_j$, and if the attacker knows everything the legitimate user does, then they can also compute all the same things.

Comment: More generally, while you've done a commendable job in actually providing a use case and a potential attack scenario for your scheme, it's still a bit unclear to me what it's actually supposed to achieve. It kind of sounds like you're trying to design some kind of a [ratchet](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/39762/what-is-a-ratchet) scheme, but I'm not sure if that's actually the case. Also, it's not clear to me what the three variables $a$, $b$ and $c$ are meant for, and why there are three instead of two or four? In all your examples, only $a$ ever seems to change AFAICT.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen: The attacker (same as the user) does not know the exponents $a,b,c$ of each of those factors. Toy example with only one factor: Your $e_0$ is 7. You know another $e_j$  which is 5. Neither a attacker nor the user should know how to compute $e_j$ out of $e_0$. The attacker knows it is something like $e_j = e_0T_p^{a_{0j}} mod P$, he knows the variables, in toy example: $5 = 7*6^{a_{0j}} mod 13$, the variable $a_{0j}$ he don't know and need to derive. As alternative he could also compute $a_{0j}$ out $a_j$ and $a_0$ for $e_j = T_p^{a_j} mod P$ and $e_0 = T_p^{a_0} mod P$,

Comment: @IlmariKaronen 2.0:  $a,b,c$ are the exponents of those factors. e.g. $PQQRPQQRR = P^aQ^bR^c$ with $a=2$, $b=4$, $a=3$. But those are not written in source code. If you multiply a given $e_0$ with e.g. a number $Q$ you only know the exponent $b$ increased by one. You don't know the actual size of $b$. Each user has his own $e_0$, this can he multiply with $P,Q,R$ as like to get some new $e$'s. Other than for a ratchet the use case will also have inverse elements of $P,Q,R$ to reduce the exponents again. So he can move his ratchet back and forth.

Comment: Question: instead of depending on Dlogs, why not use some construct like $e_{n+1} = \text{Hash}(e_n)$?  What property are you depending on that your construction provides that this simpler one doesn't?

Comment: @IlmariKaronen 3.0: Furthermore due to the other factors he can also tilt it in two additional orthogonal directions.With this the ratchet should look like a 3D torus. Every user has the same ratchet ($P,Q,R,N$) but a different rotation $e_0$. He can look around for small $a_s,b_s,c_s$ and check out some $e_s$ with $e_s=e_0P^{a_s}Q^{b_s}R^{c_s}$. With this finding a $e_0$ form another user will be rare because of big numbers.That's the the aim of to use case. It has 3 factors because use case need to be cyclic in 3 directions. You can change $a,b,c$ as you like, added more cases in top post.

Comment: @poncho: You need to be able to progress in 3 directions, back and forth, cyclic and with unique results. If there is a (set) of hash functions which can this, that would work as well. It need to encrypt the amount of used hash functions for each direction. Just 3 hash functions which work back and forth would be too unsecure, same as the separate form in main post. With this you just need to change the value of one direction until it matches the target value in same direction. Would only be $\mathcal{O}(M^{1/3})$ and further reduction through used algorithm $\mathcal{O}(M^{1/6})$ (or?)